# What does "te-thrum" mean?

Tags: word-choice, literature, poetry, neologisms

I'm reading Malcolm Lowry's letters and his first letter to Conrad Aiken finishes like this:

### te-thrum te-thrum te-thrum te-thrum, Malcolm Lowry

Does anyone know what "te-thrum" mean in this case?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In Lowry's [1928](https://archive.org/details/selectedletterso00lowr/page/4/mode/2up?q=te-thrum) letter to Aiken, the echoic phrase 'te-thrum' is an homage to Aiken's [1927](https://archive.org/details/bluevoyage0000aike/page/188/mode/2up?q=te-thrum) novel, *Blue Voyage*. In *Blue Voyage*, "te thrum" appears repeatedly in the narrator's internal monolog, as a representation of the sound of the narrator's heart in his ear. Thus, Lowry and Aiken both use "te thrum" to represent the sound of a blood pulse.

> Is it my heart or is it the engine? *Te thrum: te thrum.*
>
> op. cit., p. 189

> *Te thrum te thrum.* In my left ear my heart. …
> In my left ear my heart *Te thrum te thrum.*
>
> op. cit., p. 190